# Generating new ID for column if ROW - PREVIOUS_ROW >= 45 seconds?

Tags: python, csv, time-series

I don't want this code to be distributed

Comment: I might not understand the problem..it looks like you've already solved it. Just create an empty list "trip_id = []" and append the trip_id of each row to it as you iterate through the csv...you already have the logic there commented out. If the "if" statement is true, just use trip_id.append(trip_id[-1] + 1)), else trip_id.append(trip_id[-1]).

Comment: Thanks @Jon, I think I have the logic down, just don't know how to implement that. Looking into datetime module (everything is read in as a string).What are your thoughts on that? I like your idea of using that list and +- the trip_id based on that.

Comment: There does not appear to be a GIS component to your pure Python question. [so] is the place to research/ask similar questions to this.

Comment: @PolyGeo The GIS component is the lat/long values, grouping them by id, then finding a way to do what I am asking with the timestamps to differentiate trips for the same id. This is a clear GIS problem

Comment: In that respect they are no different than any other numeric values.

Comment: @PolyGeo I understand, but this thread is the best chance for my question to be answered... by fellow geospatial professionals. The end goal is to group, sort by time, then add points to an array for a polyline. Software developers on other Stack Exchanges might not follow along. I am already receiving help below. Please keep this open.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It creates a sorted csv (`csv_sorted`) and appends two new columns: 'time_seconds' and 'trip_id'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def getSec(time):
    return sum(x * int(t) for x, t in zip([1, 60, 3600], reversed(time.split(":"))))

# Read in csv
my_file = r"C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\output2019_05_25-11.csv" 
csv = pd.read_csv(my_file, header=None) # note the header=None specification

trip_threshold = 45 # in seconds

# Sort CSV by scooter name, then time
csv_sorted = csv.sort_values(by=[1, 10])
trip_id = np.zeros(csv_sorted.shape[0])

# Add a column of time in seconds
csv_sorted['time_seconds'] = [getSec(t) for t in csv_sorted[10].values]

diff_times = np.diff(csv_sorted['time_seconds'])
new_trip_idcs = np.where(diff_times> trip_threshold)[0] + 1
new_scooter_idcs = np.where(csv_sorted[1].values[:-1] != csv_sorted[1].values[1:])[0] + 1
new_trip_idcs = np.sort(np.unique(np.r_[new_trip_idcs, new_scooter_idcs]))
for nti in new_trip_idcs:
    trip_id[nti:] =  trip_id[nti:] + 1
csv_sorted['trip_id'] = trip_id
```

If you need the order of your original csv preserved, you can map back to it using the "Index" column in the pandas dataframe--I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: @Wazzy24 Put it on a google drive and share the link. For the HH:MM:SS thing, you'll need a line that converts them to just seconds (datetime should do this), and then everything else should work normally.

Comment: @Wazzy24 Can you explain more what you're trying to do? You mention "trips" but all I see is one time in the csv--presumably either a check-in or check-out time. How do you want to define a "trip"? Just whenever that time is greater than 45 seconds from one row to the next? I ask because the maximum time difference between times is 24 seconds, so using a threshold of 45 seconds would assign all rows the same trip_id (of 0). Nevertheless, I put updated code that includes the conversion of the HH:MM:SS to just seconds.

Comment: Ok, so the first thing you need to do is to collect each scooter's entries; i.e. sort based on scooter id (which is presumably that 13 character hash-looking string). Then for each of those you want to determine when new trips have started. Is that right? @Wazzy24

Comment: @Wazzy24 check out the new code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The scooter_trips dictionary contains each start time of each trip for each scooter. Edit: oh, do you want to  add a column to the spreadsheet that tracks trip_id?

Comment: Ok, I made one more edit. I am out of time to work on this, so I hope this accomplishes what you want. In the future, it would be helpful if you provide an expected output--i.e. state exactly what you want done. In this case, it would be something like "I want to assign a new trip id to each scooter whenever its time stamp jumps more than a threshold amount." Oftentimes by thinking extensively about how to ask your question, you will stumble across a new idea!